# Given a two element set $\{0,1 \}$, we want to find a bijection between $\{ 0,1 \}^{\omega}$ and a proper subset of itself

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $X = \{ 0,1 \}$. Find a bijective correspondence between
> $X^{\omega} = X \times X \times .... $ and a proper subset of itself.

### Attempt to the solution:

Notice that since $\{0 \} \subset \{0,1 \}$, then the set $B = \{0 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times .... $ is a proper subset of $X^{\omega}$. So we may define a function $f: B \to X^{\omega} $ as

$$ f(0,0,0,0,.....) = (1,1,....) $$

and this would trivially be bijective. Is this correct?

Comment: How is that surjective?

Comment: What about $ f(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)=(0,a_1,a_2,...)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything like @J.W. Tanner suggests $f_n(a_1,a_2,\dots)=(0,\dots,0,a_1,a_2,a_3, \dots)$, where the first $n$ coordinates are zero, will work.

Comment: I see. But it may not need to be the first n. The point is to take $X^{w} \to A $ where $A \subset X^{w} $ right ?

Comment: Right.  It needn't be the first $n$.  Yes, that's the idea.  The map's image needs to have the same cardinality as $X^\omega$, yet still be a proper subset.  This will happen if the map is injective, but not surjective.  Of course it will still be a bijection onto its image.